# Unable to deploy Rails app on Heroku due to asset pipeline error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a simple Rails app that I want to deploy on Heroku so that I can get some user testing and feedback. I am having problems with deploying it on Heroku, however, because I am getting an error that is essentially saying it is unable to find the `image1.jpeg` in my asset pipeline. However, I am deploying from my GitHub, which I have confirmed has all the images in the asset pipeline.

This is the official error log on Heorku:

```
2020-04-18T18:44:57.915542+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=finalproj493.herokuapp.com request_id=2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc fwd="99.28.183.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2020-04-18T18:44:57.910183+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-18T18:44:57.910093 #4]  INFO -- : [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc] Started GET "/" for 99.28.183.27 at 2020-04-18 18:44:57 +0000
2020-04-18T18:44:57.910888+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-18T18:44:57.910825 #4]  INFO -- : [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc] Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2020-04-18T18:44:57.912171+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-18T18:44:57.912112 #4]  INFO -- : [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]   Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2020-04-18T18:44:57.912529+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-18T18:44:57.912475 #4]  INFO -- : [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 120)
2020-04-18T18:44:57.912717+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-18T18:44:57.912663 #4]  INFO -- : [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Allocations: 424)
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914850+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-04-18T18:44:57.914793 #4] FATAL -- : [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]   
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914851+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "image1.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     14:     <br>
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     15: 
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     16:     <div>
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     17:         <%= image_tag(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("image1.jpeg"), :size =>"350x500") %>
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     18:     </div>
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     19: 
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]     20:     <br>
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc]   
2020-04-18T18:44:57.914855+00:00 app[web.1]: [2533d3cb-5dee-4052-bb56-98b4f7fd65dc] app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:17
```

I can get this to locally run just fine, but I am unable to run it on Heroku. Whenever I try to go to the project's Heroku URl, it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong".

I have tried the following:
[Running heroku db:rake and db:migrate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017668/heroku-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: Why are you using `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("image1.jpeg")` instead of `image_path('image1.jpeg')`? Any reason? you shouldn't need to use `config.assets.compile = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer! It is a one-liner, you must go to `production.rb` and change it to:

```
  config.assets.compile = true
```